# What is the difference between ggplot and ggplot2?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, package

everyone! I am new to [r](/questions/tagged/r). I have a disease rate data from different counties and I want to visualize them on the map.

I follow the instructions on this website:https://socviz.co/maps.html

I wanted to try their example first but R gave me a wrong message:

```
> p <- ggplot(data = county_full,
        mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat,
                      fill = pop_dens, 
                       group = group))
```

> Error in ggplot(data = county_full, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat,  : 
>         could not find function "ggplot"

I want to install the ggplot but it said:

> Warning in install.packages :package ‘ggplot’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

I don't know how to modify the code so that I can use [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) to try their examples.

Thanks!

Comment: `ggplot` is the main function of the package `ggplot2`. Install `ggplot2`, load this library (`library(ggplot2)` and you will be able to sue the function `ggplot`

Comment: The package is called ggplot2. So try `install.packages ("ggplot2")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rounds up the idea by @dc37:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + geom_point()
```

`ggplot2` is the package and `ggplot()` is the main function.